# Algolia search result is overidding css format

Tags: javascript, html, css, algolia

I am searching using algolia search. Everything works but instead of the search result to displaying in columns it's only showing in a list format

This is the display in normal html code 
[image]
but when algolia search result is used to populate the container using the code below this is what it shows 
[image]

I have this html file

```
    <div class="row isotope-grid" id="hits" >
        <!-- Load more -->
        <div class="flex-c-m flex-w w-full p-t-45">
            <a href="#" class="flex-c-m stext-101 cl5 size-103 bg2 bor1 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04">
                Load More
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is the JS format

```
         var search = instantsearch({
          // Replace with your own values
                appId: 'E525782525525',
                apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxx, 
                indexName: 'Listing',
                urlSync: true,
                searchParameters: {
                  query: "2",
                  // hitsPerPage: 10
                }
              });


         search.addWidget(
           instantsearch.widgets.hits({
            container: '#hits',
            templates: {
              empty: 'No results',
              item: `

                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-b-35 isotope-item ">
                <!-- Block2 -->
                <div class="block2">
                    <div class="block2-pic hov-img0">
                        <img src="images/product-03.jpg" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">
                        <a href="#" class="block2-btn flex-c-m stext-103 cl2 size-102 bg0 bor2 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-show-modal1">
                            Quick View
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="block2-txt flex-w flex-t p-t-14">
                        <div class="block2-txt-child1 flex-col-l ">
                            <a href="product-detail.html" class="stext-104 cl4 hov-cl1 trans-04 js-name-b2 p-b-6">
                                Only Check Trouser
                            </a>

                            <span class="stext-105 cl3">
                                $25.50
                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="block2-txt-child2 flex-r p-t-3">
                            <a href="#" class="btn-addwish-b2 dis-block pos-relative js-addwish-b2">
                                <img class="icon-heart1 dis-block trans-04" src="images/icons/icon-heart-01.png" alt="ICON">
                                <img class="icon-heart2 dis-block trans-04 ab-t-l" src="images/icons/icon-heart-02.png" alt="ICON">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

              `
              ,

               }
              })
            );
          search.start();
```

I have been able to rule out the css and discovered that ALgolia is overriding the display. How do I modify the code to show a custom display of columns instead of the default Algolia list display?

after implementing Dipen Shah's answer, it partially worked and produced to wierd overlap upon rendering but the overlapp disappears if the window is width or height is decreased and return back to full size.

here is what the overlap looks like
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that same class is exist in the data which is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing very crucial function call which is why your search result is not being rendered properly.

1. Remove `isotope-grid` class from `div#hits`

```html
<!-- Load more -->
<div class="row" id="hits">
  <div class="flex-c-m flex-w w-full p-t-45">
    <a href="#" class="flex-c-m stext-101 cl5 size-103 bg2 bor1 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04">
      Load More
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Initialize `hits` div with isotope grid after search result is render.

```js
search.on('render', function(){
    $grid = $("#hits");
    $grid.isotope('destroy');
    $grid.isotope({
  itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  percentPosition: true,
  animationEngine : 'best-available',
  masonry: {
   columnWidth: '.isotope-item'
  }
 });
});
```

After this changes, search result will be rendered correctly.

**Explanation:**

In the original theme file, on page load event script calls following call to initialize grids.

```js
$(window).on('load', function () {
    var $grid = $topeContainer.each(function () {
        $(this).isotope({
            itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
            layoutMode: 'fitRows',
            percentPosition: true,
            animationEngine : 'best-available',
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: '.isotope-item'
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When algolia widget renders search result, your template sets correct css classes but you still need to initialize `isotope` grid for your search result container. My code does exactly that by intercepting `render` event of the widget.

Comment: it partially worked, I've updated the question with information. What could be causing the overlap?

Comment: @learner101 Cannot reproduce issue, check my code https://pastebin.com/z5B4Tr6c, If you can post your code I can further check for issue

Comment: @lerner101 Can you post your full code, code that you sent in pastebin works correctly on my pc on chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178798/discussion-between-dipen-shah-and-learner101).

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

I don't think you're using the correct method for a template.

The docs for Aloglia gives [this example](https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/search-ui/instant-search/build-an-instant-search-results-page/instantsearchjs/?language=php#displaying-results):

> **Javascript**:
>
> ```
> search.addWidget(
>   instantsearch.widgets.hits({
>     container: '#hits',
>     templates: {
>       item: document.getElementById('hit-template').innerHTML,
>       empty: "We didn't find any results for the search <em>\"{{query}}\"</em>"
>     }
>   })
> );
> ```
>
> **HTML**:
>
> ```
> <!-- Add this to your HTML document -->
> <script type="text/html" id="hit-template">
>   <div class="hit">
>     <div class="hit-image">
>       <img src="{{image}}" alt="{{name}}">
>     </div>
>     <div class="hit-content">
>       <h3 class="hit-price">${{price}}</h3>
>       <h2 class="hit-name">{{{_highlightResult.name.value}}}</h2>
>       <p class="hit-description">{{{_highlightResult.description.value}}}</p>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </script>
> ```

## Solution

This means you need something like this: (replacing the placeholders accordingly)

**Javascript:**

```js
// Replace with your own values
appId: 'E525782525525',
  apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxx, 
indexName: 'Listing',
  urlSync: true,
  searchParameters: {
    query: "2",
    // hitsPerPage: 10
  }
});


search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.hits({
    container: '#hits',
    templates: {
      empty: 'No results',
      item: document.getElementById('hit-template').innerHTML,

    }
  })
);
search.start();
```

**HTML:**

```html
<!-- Add this to your HTML document -->
<script type="text/html" id="hit-template">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-b-35 isotope-item ">
    <!-- Block2 -->
    <div class="block2">
      <div class="block2-pic hov-img0">
        <img src="{{image}}" alt="{{name}}">
        <a href="#" class="block2-btn flex-c-m stext-103 cl2 size-102 bg0 bor2 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-show-modal1">Quick View</a>
      </div>

      <div class="block2-txt flex-w flex-t p-t-14">
        <div class="block2-txt-child1 flex-col-l ">
          <a href="product-detail.html" class="stext-104 cl4 hov-cl1 trans-04 js-name-b2 p-b-6">${{product_name}}</a>

          <span class="stext-105 cl3">${{price}}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="block2-txt-child2 flex-r p-t-3">
          <a href="#" class="btn-addwish-b2 dis-block pos-relative js-addwish-b2">
            <img class="icon-heart1 dis-block trans-04" src="images/icons/icon-heart-01.png" alt="ICON">
            <img class="icon-heart2 dis-block trans-04 ab-t-l" src="images/icons/icon-heart-02.png" alt="ICON">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</script>
```

Comment: I tried this and the rendering of the search is still vertical

Comment: @learner101 Can you confirm that your CSS file(s) are still being loaded?

Comment: Yes it is loaded. it works fine and display correctly if the algolia is not used. this is the template that i am using https://colorlib.com/preview/#cozastore